# Proving Big Omega Function

Tags: algorithm, function, big-o, proof

I'm trying to find the n0 (n not) of a function with a big omega size of n^3 where c=2.25

() = 3^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20. In order to prove that () is Ω(^3), we need constants , 0 > 0 such that () ≥ ^3 for every  ≥ 0

If c=2.25, how do I find the smallest integer that satisfies n0?

My first thought was to plug in n=1, because n>0, and if the inequality worked n=1 would be the smallest n (therefore n0). But, the inequality has to be satisfied for every n>=n0, and if i plug in, for example, n=15 the inequality doesn't work.

Comment: It's `max(1, ceil(r))` where `r` is the largest root of `f(n)-cn^3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this mathematically.

To make sure that I understand what you want, I will summarize what you are asking. You want to find the smallest integer n so that:

3^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20 ≥ 2.25^3 (1)

And any other integers bigger than n must also satisfy the equation (1).

**So here is my solution:**

(1) <=> 0.75^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20 ≥ 0

Let f(n) = 0.75^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20

f(n) = 0 <=> n1 = -0.05522 or n2 = 12.079 or n3 = 39.976

- If n < n1, f(n) < 0 (try this yourself)
- If n1 < n < n2, f(n) > 0 (the sign will alternate)
- If n2 < n < n3, f(n) < 0 (the sign will alternate, again)
- If n > n3, f(n) > 0

So to satisfy your requirements, the minimum value of n must be 40

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by <=>

Comment: <=> means if and only if

Comment: @chrisd1120: did you get that or you need more explanation? Please let me know what I could help.

Answer (score -1):

Think about it like this. After a certain point 3^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20 will always be greater than or equal to n^3 for the simple fact that eventually 3n^3 will beat out the -39n^2. So F(n) will never dip below n^3 for an extremely large number. You don't have to put the minimum nO, just choose an extremely large number for nO, since the question is asking after a certain value for n, the statement will hold true for ever. Choose nO, for example, to be an extremely large number X, and then use an inductive proof where X is the base case.